# How to approach this correctly?

Tags: php, html

I am making a webpage with news articles. What I want is when I click on an article on my website, I can see title, publish date, summary and content. But I'm trying to code efficiently and I'm trying to use 2 files.

1 with php and 1 with html/php mixed. What I'm trying here is to use the get a method to get the title of the article I click on the home page and to assign that value to my string title in my article.php file. Is this the right way?

I'm new to php and I don't have that much experience in html. So any feedback is welcome!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    /* The home page*/
    $the_title = 'Home';
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $the_publish_date = date('d F');
    $article_title = array('Lichaam vermiste Nederlander in Schotland vermoedelijk gevonden',
                           'Onze gadgets worden steeds slimmer, maar niet per se beter');
    $summary = array('De Schotse politie heeft donderdag vermoedelijk het lichaam gevonden van een Nederlandse man, die al meer dan een week wordt vermist in de Schotse Hooglanden ', 'Het is al jarenlang een trend: steeds meer gadgets krijgen een internetverbinding en worden slim. Ook dit jaar zijn er op gadgetbeurs CES weer veel slimme apparaten te bewonderen, maar ook veel slimme prullaria.');        
    ?>
    <?php
    include('HomeHTML.php');
```

My HTML page:

```php
<?php include('Header.php'); ?>
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <h2><?php echo $the_title ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $the_publish_date ?></p> 
        <h3><a href="Article.php" target="_blank" name = "name"><?php echo $article_title[0] ?></a></h3>
        <br></br>
        <?php echo $summary[0] ?>
        <br></br>
        <p><?php echo $the_publish_date ?></p> 
        <h3><a href="Article.php" target="_blank" name = "name"><?php echo $article_title[1] ?></a></h3>
        <br></br>
        <?php echo $summary[1] ?>
        <?php
        include('Footer.php');
```

My article.php:

```
?php
 $article = $_GET['name'];     
?>
<?php
include('ArticleHTML.php');?>
```

My article HTML:

```
<?php include('Header.php'); ?>
<div id="content">
<div id="main">
<h2><?php$article?></h2>
<?php
include('Footer.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

This could one way to do this:
`<h3><a href="Article.php?name=<?php echo urlencode($article_title[0]); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $article_title[1] ?></a></h3>`

**but watch out! If you do it this way, you have to ensure that u escape the $_GET['name'] Parameter in article.php, otherwise your script is vulnerable for XSS**

Edit: urlencode ...